# How to convert a string to a time, make it time-zone aware, and convert the timezone in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a column called 'Status Date' with thousands of dates formatted like this:

```
Status Date
01/04/2021-12:21:36
```

in the pattern:

```
m/d/Y-H:M:S
```

I need all the elements of this column to be converted to a time-zone aware DateTime object in  UTC, and the times to be subsequently converted to UTC-0600 (America/Chicago). I attempted to fix it myself using this:

```
merged['Status Date'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['Status Date'], errors='coerce')
merged['Status Date'] = merged['Status Date'].dt.tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('America/Chicago')
```

However this ignores the date formatting I have and doesn't read in a time, instead converting everything to 00:00:00, and then to 18:00:00-06:00. When I run this, I get this output:

```
2021-01-03 18:00:00-06:00
```

which disregards the time and pushes everything back 6 hours from 00:00:00.

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like I'm close.

Comment: parsing that datetime string format works out-of-the-box for me; tested `pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["01/04/2021-12:21:36"], utc=True)).dt.tz_convert('America/Chicago')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your `to_datetime()` creation

```py
merged['Status Date'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['Status Date'],
    errors='coerce', format='m/d/Y-H:M:S')
```

Comment: setting a specific format and errors=coerce will help if this is a parsing issue, i.e. if there are improper H:M:S for example.